# Python Grabbing Most recent file After script is ran

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing a data parsing script where the data is refreshing every hour. I have the script working and it grabs the recent file from when the script is ran for the first time. But if an update gets delivered when the script is currently running it cannot detect the new file. This wasnt an issue when It was running in putty but I'm recreating everything in flask.

```
def getLatestFile():
    import glob, os
    list_of_files = glob.glob('./Source/data.parsed*.txt')
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    return latest_file

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ###Creates a Dictionary from the latest Data File
    headers = None
    content = {}
    csvFile = getLatestFile()
    modTime = os.path.getmtime(csvFile)
    reader=csv.reader(open(csvFile), delimiter = '|') #opens File
    print('Creating Dictionary from file ' + csvFile + '\nLast modified date - ' + str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(modTime)))
    for row in reader: # Writes data to dictionary
       if reader.line_num == 1:
           headers = row[1:] #grabs first row and creates headers
           print(headers)
       else:
           content[row[0]] = dict(zip(headers, row[1:])) #creates dictionary
    app.run(host=os.getenv('IP', '0.0.0.0'), port =int(os.getenv('PORT', 8080)), debug=True)
```

When I try and recreate the dictionary with this code below it only grabs the most recent file from when the script is created

```
def updateDict():
    headers = None
    content = {}
    csvFile = getLatestFile()
    modTime = os.path.getmtime(csvFile)
    for row in reader: # Writes data to dictionary
       if reader.line_num == 1:
           headers = row[1:] #grabs first row and creates headers
       else:
           content[row[0]] = dict(zip(headers, row[1:])) #creates dictionary
```

I have tried `latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getmtime)` instead  but it still ignores the new files that are dropped into the source directory.

Comment: don't use `os.path.getctime` use `os.path.getmtime` (modification time)

Comment: I gave that a go but it still ignores the new files that are dropped into the source file

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.getctime()` works in strange ways:

> Return the system’s ctime which, on some systems (like Unix) is the time of the last metadata change, and, on others (like Windows), is the creation time for path.

So it's good to detect which file has been created the last, but not to detect if an already existing file has been modified.

I suggest to alter your key to compute the max between creation time and modification time:

```
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=lambda x : max(os.path.getmtime(x),os.path.getctime(x)))
```

Comment: Tried your change but it still doesnt use the most recent file that is dropped into the source folder after the script runs.


def getLatestFile():
    list_of_files = glob.glob('./Source/data.parsed*.txt') # used for testing
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=lambda x : max(os.path.getmtime(x),os.path.getctime(x)))
    return latest_file

Comment: it's surprising as the highest date wins whatever it is. You could try to print `sorted(list_of_files, key=lambda x : max(os.path.getmtime(x),os.path.getctime(x)))` and see which ones come first/last to debug.

Comment: also you could try `os.path.getatime` (access time)

Comment: This just happened too. I started the script with the new file I was testing with and it found it. I then removed that file from the directory and hit update dictionary and it still grabs the removed file as the newest

Comment: it's not possible that a removed file shows up in `glob.glob` output.

Comment: Could it be the getLatestFile() isn't updating its variables

Comment: no, `glob.glob` scans the disk each time it's called

Comment: I've tried to change some variables so names are not repeated and it still doesn't update whats listed in the directory. I also removed getLatestFiles() from the update part and added

list_of_files2 = glob.glob('./Source/data.parsed*.txt') 
    latest_file2 = max(list_of_files2, key=lambda x : max(os.path.getmtime(x),os.path.getctime(x)))
    csvFile2 = latest_file2

Comment: hmmmm are you sure there isn't another `'./Source` directory somewhere with a copy of the files ? try with absolute path.

Comment: It wasn't an error with glob.glob. it was a silly human error. But i've kept your suggestions, thank you very much! Wish I had more rep so I can +1 you

Comment: no problem. You can still accept the answer, but only if it was useful to you because of the difference between mtime and ctime.